# How to merge all footer widgets to a single widget

Tags: wordpress, merge, footer

I was working with my website. I want to merge all my 4 footer widgets into a single widget. But I want it as 4 widgets also. I want two rows in footer. In first one, all widgets should merge to a single widget and in the second one I need all widgets individually.

I don't know how to add a picture here. Otherwise i would have made the question much more simpler

I have tried some additional CSS codes that i found on some sites. But that really didn't help me.

### Expected Result

- Footer with 2 rows
- 1st row - all 4 widgets combined to a single widgets
- 2nd row - 4 widgets as it is for different items.

Comment: The question needs clarification.  Are you talking about reducing the number of widget locations available in the theme?  Or are you simply talking about changing visual appearance so the widgets stack vertically or something to that effect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse. You can create a single widget for `row 1` and another for `row 2`.
create a single widget as normal.

In the admin panel, we have the options for adding custom options (Custom Menu). Add the required 4 menus in that widget and style it.
 repeat the same for the next.